# How to calculate time-series column in r using another column?

Tags: r

I am new to r and I am trying to calculate some basic stuff. I have 2 time-series columns, time and velocity and in data frame I am trying to add column of acceleration and don't know how to do it:

```r
df_x$Acceleration <- df_x$Velocity.....
```

formula for time-series acceleration that I want to use is:

[image]

Basically I have a problem how to calculate the numerator.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
t.plus.one <- 1:nrow(df_x) + 1
t.minus.one <- 1:nrow(df_x) - 1
t <- 1:nrow(df_x)

df_x$Acceleration <- (df_x$Velocity[t.plus.one] - df_x$Velocity[t.minus.one]) / t
```

This will of course lead to an error, because the indices are not in range. However, you can easily fix that buy constructing the `df` such that this does not occur.

Comment: Worked thank you! Just I needed to replace nrows with nrow.

Comment: Great! I edited my answer. Please also consider to up vote the answer.